# Parser error: Unexpected token at column error after angular update to 12

Tags: angular, angular12

I am getting this build error - NG 5002 Parser error : unexpected token "=" at column 2 in the below component.html file line

```
<button id="asd" [disabled]="sendMail.Invalid" type="button" (click)="hideexampleMail()">
```

Another place i am also getting the same error, ie

```
<div *ngIf="showExmapleMail"></div>
```

I was migrating my angular 8 application to Angular 12.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you post more of the html?

Answer (score 4):

Since the template validation is more strict with Angular 12, the problem might be caused by an undefined value. You might want to try:

```html
<button id="asd" [disabled]="sendMail?.Invalid" type="button" (click)="hideexampleMail()">
```

Comment: Hi eko thanks for that info  i am also getting error in *ngIf="showExmapleMail" so is that mean i need to change this line to *ngIf="showExmapleMail?"       ???  .

Comment: Have you initialized the value for `showExmapleMail` variable ?

Comment: BTW, could you share your class for the template above?

Comment: @RomanA. is right. You just need to be more careful with the falsy values that comes from your component/ts files. If you could post more of your code, it would be easier to identify the errors.

Comment: Hi thanks i am not able to post my entire code since i am working in VM. What about this line Eko and Roman - <button id="asd" type="button" (click)="hideexampleMail()"> Here you can see that i am not using any typescript variables, but still i am getting parser error here, any idea?

Comment: It's probably not that line throwing the error. However, very small chance that maybe something inside the `hideexampleMail` is causing an exception.

Comment: @eko i chekd inside of hideexampleMail(), in this i can see one boolean variable which is declared at class level and setting its value as false inside this method nothing else.

Comment: Without more code it's really difficult to guess :/